# OpenCV missing header files

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I downloaded OpenCV 3.0.0 and I compiled with `WITH_QT` and it compiled awesomely but when I look into the folder `build/install/include/opencv2` there's only one file called `opencv.hpp` and inside:

```
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/photo.hpp"
#include "opencv2/video.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/ml.hpp"
```

The problem is that those files doesn't exist in that directory.

I'm in a 64bit Windows and I used Visual Studio 2013 to compile OpenCV because Qt uses Visual Studio as default compiler on 64bit Windows, and the weird thing is that the examples compiles and everything works, but when I try to create a project on Qt and insert that directory as include path I got an error saying that `opencv2/core.hpp` doesn't exist. I tried to include direct from `opencv/modules/core/include` the the error persists.

What is happening? What is the propose to exist one single file that includes others locally if there's no other files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after building opencv via cmake, you should build the INSTALL project (this is not done automatically).

this will copy everything nessecary to build/install/include

Comment: you should *build* the install project.